# Oracle Oracle hierarchical query to disable foreign keys

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-query

I have some code (see below), which uses a hierarchical query that traverses down a table to find all the related Foriegn keys. This seems to be working fine.

Can this be modified not to display the top level table, in this case the `TABLE_NAME`=`'PARENT'` as I want to wrap this code in PL/SQL in order to create the desired syntax to enable/disable Foriegn keys for all the descendants of a table.

In my example, I have 3 tables. A grandchild table, which `REFERENCES` a child table and a child table, which `REFERENCES` the parent table, which is the master table.

The reason for this is to clean up some massive tables and I am trying to figure out the most effective and efficient way to go about this exercise.

We don't have `CASCADE DELETE` setup as that is too dangerous and some people learned that the hard way unfortunately.

Below is my test case and expected results, which I plan to execute in a procedure.

```sql
create table parent (
  id NUMBER(10),
  value      varchar2(30),
constraint parent_pk primary key (id)
);

CREATE TABLE child
( id NUMBER(10) not null,
value NUMBER(10) not null,
constraint child_pk primary key (id,value),
CONSTRAINT parent_child_fk
FOREIGN KEY (id)
REFERENCES parent(id));

CREATE TABLE grandchild
( id NUMBER(10) not null,
value NUMBER(10) not null,
constraint grandchild_pk primary key (id,value),
CONSTRAINT child_grandchild_fk
FOREIGN KEY (id,value)
REFERENCES child(id,value));

insert into parent values (1,'a');
insert into parent values (2,'b');
insert into parent values (3,'c');

insert into child  values (1,1);
insert into child  values (1,2);
insert into child  values (1,3);
insert into child  values (2,1);
insert into child  values (2,2);
insert into child  values (2,3);
insert into child  values (3,1);
insert into child  values (3,2);
insert into child  values (3,3);

insert into grandchild  values (1,1);
insert into grandchild  values (1,2);
insert into grandchild  values (1,3);
insert into grandchild  values (2,1);
insert into grandchild  values (2,2);
insert into grandchild  values (2,3);
insert into grandchild  values (3,1);
insert into grandchild  values (3,2);
insert into grandchild  values (3,3);
```

In the query I hard code the column name ID.

If possible, I would like to figure it out else I can live with the hard coded value.

```sql
select distinct table_name, constraint_name, column_name, r_table_name, position, constraint_type 
from (
    SELECT uc.table_name, 
    uc.constraint_name, 
    cols.column_name, 
    (select table_name from user_constraints where constraint_name = uc.r_constraint_name) 
        r_table_name,
    (select column_name from user_cons_columns where constraint_name = uc.r_constraint_name and position = cols.position) 
        r_column_name,
    cols.position,
    uc.constraint_type
    FROM user_constraints uc
    inner join user_cons_columns cols on uc.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name 
    where constraint_type != 'C'
) 
start with table_name = 'PARENT' and column_name = 'ID'  
connect by nocycle 
prior table_name = r_table_name 
and prior column_name = r_column_name;
```

| TABLE_NAME | CONSTRAINT_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | R_TABLE_NAME | POSITION | CONSTRAINT_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PARENT | PARENT_PK | ID | - | 1 | P |
| GRANDCHILD | CHILD_GRANDCHILD_FK | ID | CHILD | 1 | R |
| CHILD | PARENT_CHILD_FK | ID | PARENT | 1 | R |

Expected results for my test CASE is to generate this syntax:

```sql
alter table CHILD disable constraint PARENT_CHILD_FK;
alter table GRANDCHILD disable constraint CHILD_GRANDCHILD_FK;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE "' || u.owner || '"."' || u.table_name || '" '
       || 'DISABLE CONSTRAINT "' || u.constraint_name || '"' AS statement
FROM   user_constraints u
       INNER JOIN user_constraints r
       ON (   u.constraint_type = 'R'
          AND r.constraint_type IN ('P', 'U')
          AND u.r_owner = r.owner
          AND u.r_constraint_name = r.constraint_name)
START WITH r.table_name       = 'PARENT'
CONNECT BY PRIOR u.owner      = r.owner
AND        PRIOR u.table_name = r.table_name;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=53ede61631235bf0fd8c6ea8925b32f3)*

Comment: MTO perfect!!! This is exactly what I was looking for. Now I can avoid a procedure and just cut and paste the solution.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to use hard code, in fact, it is more troublesome to display the top-level table

```sql
with tab1 as (
select t1.CONSTRAINT_NAME,
       t1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE,
       t1.TABLE_NAME,
       t1.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME,
       t2.CONSTRAINT_TYPE r_type,
       t2.TABLE_NAME r_name
  from user_constraints t1,
       user_constraints t2
 where t1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R'
   and t1.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME = t2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
)
, tab2 as(
select t1.*
  from tab1 t1
 start with not exists(
       select 1 from tab1 v1 where t1.r_name = v1.table_name
 )
 connect by prior t1.table_name = t1.r_name
)
select 'alter table ' || t1.table_name || ' disable constraint ' || t1.CONSTRAINT_NAME || ';'
  from tab2 t1
;
```

Comment: nayi224 thanks for responding and your eloquent solution. I don't see a hard coded table so will this query pick up ALL tables? If so, that isn't what I want. I only want the tables related directly or indirectly to the top level table. In this case 'PARENT'. Or am i misinterpreting your solution

Comment: This query will find each set of tables that have a foreign key relationship. With connect_by_root() and sys_connect_by_path(), you can better observe what this query does